# Windows 10 pro 64 bit - Remote Desktop can't move files

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10

I am able to connect 2 computers both running Windows 10 Pro and using the new remote desktop available from the Microsoft store as a free app. My problem is I can't move any files like I used to be able to do with one 8.1 machine to a 7.0 machine. I using my Microsoft Account login on both machines where before I used a local logon. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: How did you use to move files? Have you tried simply copy and pasting. That option is available through RDP usually.

Comment: Yes copy and paste used to work on windows 8.1 pro and windows 7.0 pro but not now. Paste is grayed out in Windows 10

Comment: So your PC is A, then remote PC B and C. If you Copy on B then paste on A, then copy on A and paste on C. That doesn't work either?

Comment: No I can't paste anywhere! **Paste is grayed both ways.** PC A to PC B or PC B to PC A.